# Blender to unity : Send the texture tiling information

Tags: unity

i imported .blend file into unity. In blender, i don't want to control the texture mapping by modifying the UV , but i used 'texture coordinate' and 'mapping' node in shader editor to control the tiling (edit the scale parameter of that mapping node). Can i bring this 'texture tiling' information to unity via .blend file ?

Comment: Export as .fbx it will give you the mesh with the textures. I don't think all the shaders will be sent

Comment: I need the 'texture tiling' information (not the texture) set by 'mapping' node in shader editor. If it's just the texture , i can simply bring via .blend file into unity with 'pack/unpack material' tool. Texture tiling from fbx is just 1x1.